# how to run Invoke-ASCmd in Linux?

Tags: sql-server, linux, powershell, ascmd

I'm running powershell command on a linux server, and I have powershell for linux as well as the SqlServer installed, but when I run `Invoke-ASCmd` I got

```
Invoke-ASCmd: The term 'Invoke-ASCmd' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
```

Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Here are the version of my powershell and SqlServer module:

```
PS /> Get-Host | Select-Object Version

Version
-------
7.1.3

PS /> Get-Module -Name SqlServer

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                ----------------
Script     21.1.18245            SqlServer                           {Add-SqlAvailabilityDatabase, Add-SqlAvailabilityGroupListenerStaticIp, Add-SqlColumnEncryptionKeyValue, Add-SqlLogin…}
```

I could run `Invoke-ASCmd` locally on Windows, but it doesn't work on Linux.
Please help me with this issue, thanks so much

Comment: Here is my powershell version
PS /> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.1.3
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.1.3
OS                             Linux 5.4.0-1047-azure #49~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 22 21:28:54 UTC 2021
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0

Comment: "Note: This cmdlet is only available for PowerShell 5. Currently, it is available for PowerShell 7 in recent **preview** versions of the module."  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-ascmd?view=sqlserver-ps#description